# How do I change my character's skin color in the Union Room?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-remakes

When I go into the Union Room to trade my character's skin color, on the other person's Switch it doesn't match the one on mine. I talked to everyone upstairs and couldn't find out where to change the skin color. The other person's characters on my Switch and their Switch both match.

Where do I go to change the skin color of the remote version of my character in the Union Room?